# Autocomplete from an array not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I can't figure out what's wrong in my code.

I've checked stackoverflow for similar questions but nothing have helped me

I import my js files

```
     <link type="text/css" href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Then I write the js for the autocomplete:

```
<script>
   function log(msg) {
       $("<div>", { text: msg }).prependTo("#log");
   }

$("#elem").autocomplete({
    source: ["Javascript", "Java", "Jino"],

         minLength: 1,
         fillin:true,
         change: function (event, ui) {
           console.log(ui.item);
           }

       });

   $("#elem").autocomplete("widget").height(300);

    </script>
```

then I write the html:

```
    <input id="elem" />

    <div id="log"></div>
```

It is supposed to work, I don't get any errors on IE.
I browsed through tons of example, nothing works, I'm desperate <.<

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2d6fLepa/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/qnmyjdu5/

Comment: sure: http://jsfiddle.net/2d6fLepa/

Comment: Thanks Robert, I was missing that: " $(function(){ "
I'm a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now, Thanks to Robert

```
$(function(){
function log(msg) {
   $("<div>", { text: msg }).prependTo("#log");
}

$("#elem").autocomplete({
source: ["Javascript", "Java", "Jino"],

     minLength: 1,
     fillin:true,
     change: function (event, ui) {
       console.log(ui.item);
       }

   });

   $("#elem").autocomplete("widget").height(300);


});
```